# wp-admin dashboard redirects to homepage

Tags: wp-admin

When going to /wp-admin on the website I am working on, it simply goes to the homepage. I then tried going to /wp-login.php and the login screen shows up, but once I login, the url in the address bar says wp-admin, but it still directed me to the homepage.

I have indeed gone through the database and changed the siteurl, and I've tried numerous fixes that I've found online, but to no avail.

Something odd, though, is that I can access any pages within /wp-admin except for the index. I can go to /wp-admin/edit.php or to /wp-admin/options-general.php, etc... but the moment I click on Dashboard or Dashboard > Home, then I get kicked out of the dashboard and it goes to the homepage, but the url in the address bar still says /wp-admin/index.php ...

so, I am at a loss here. Anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: Maybe it's stupid question, but sometimes we forget the easiest solutions. Does `index.php` file in `wp-admin` directory exist?

Comment: Yes, the index.php file in the admin folder does exist. I even just cleared all of my cookies/cache and whatnot in an attempt to see if it was really a non-issue, but that didn't help either.

Comment: Strange. Have you tried to disable `.htaccess` and try then? (Just rename this file)

Comment: Disable all your plugins.  Does the issue persist? If not, turn them back on one by one till it comes up again. If it's not a plugin, switch to a default theme like Twenty Twelve.  Does the issue persist?

Comment: What did you do immediately before this started? Change hosts? Update the server? Update WordPress or a theme or plugin? What?

Comment: I migrated from a local installation to the client's webhost on godaddy.

Comment: There you have, the real issue: failed migration.